# Symfony2: How to check permissions for different users/roles on an domain object?

Tags: symfony, permissions, acl

I want to show a table with permission flags. It means who is allowed to do something.

In my Application I set all permissions in ACEs with UserSecurityIdentity/RoleSecurityIdentity and a valid mask. All values are as expected in mydatabase and I can check it for logged in user.

```
$securityContext->isGranted('EDIT', $model);
```

But how can I check if a different user or role has the permission EDIT on this object?